# SUSE Linux Enterprise Server software

Tags: latex, rpm, suse

A professor at the university asked me if I could install some software for him on his laptop that runs SLES 11. I'm not familiar with SUSE (I typically work with debian based machines) so I'm having some trouble finding/installing some software.

Here's the list of software he needs installed:

-xv (plotting software)
-xmgrace
-LaTeX

Can someone point me toward some rpms for the above-mentioned software?

I tried looking for the packages with YaST, but I haven't had any luck.

The repositories I have listed include:

SLES11-Extras
SLES11-Pool
SLES11-Updates
SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool
SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
and the install DVD.

Am I missing a repo?

Comment: It looks like those packages aren't included with SLES but are included with openSUSE.  You can download them via the [package search function](http://software.opensuse.org/) of the openSUSE website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUSE's equivalent to apt is called *zypper* and graphical installation and configuration tool is YaST.
You can access the graphical tool (SUSE's equivalent to *Synaptic*) by selecting YAST from the System menu or by running `yast` on a command-line or by pressing ALT+F2.  Then, select *Software Management* from the *Software* tab.

Those applications should be included with the software repositories offered by SUSE.

If you know the package name, you can install from the command-line just like you can with `apt-get`:

```
zypper in package-name
```

Or search for a package with `zypper se pkg..` command